# Is it possible to convert milliseconds to normal time hh:mm:ss without Javascript?

Tags: html, css, time

Currently I have a form with checkboxes and a table with several outcomes. This all works great with a Javascript. But in order to use this savely on a forum it is better to not use Javascript as these are used inside postings.

At the moment this form has several checkable options for calculating factors to decrease a standard milliseconds time, and output them in a result.
Now I want to rebuild it to not use Javascript. And that should works for above options. But those milliseconds have to show up in the end as hours : minutes : seconds.

Is this possible to achive without the use of the Java function? (and without php) So HTML or CSS only.

I already have looked in several things, like the pure CSS calculator etc, but those are all numbers only. I need a time convertion.

Currently I use this functions code

```js
// function milliseconds to time
function msTime(s) {
  var ms = s % 1000;
  s = (s - ms) / 1000;
  var secs = s % 60;
  s = (s - secs) / 60;
  var mins = s % 60;
  var hrs = (s - mins) / 60;

 mins = ("00" + mins).substr(-2);
 secs = ("00" + secs).substr(-2);

  return ' ' + hrs + 'h ' + ' ' + mins + 'm ' + ' ' + secs + 's';
}
```

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without `Javascript`. you can simplify the function as follows.

```js
var secondsToTime = function(duration) {
  var date = new Date(duration);

  return "%hours:%minutes:%seconds"
    .replace('%hours', date.getHours())
    .replace('%minutes', date.getMinutes())
    .replace('%seconds', date.getSeconds());
}

console.log(secondsToTime(1324339210310));
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this does not work for our purpouses. And we can not use Java, they would kick us off the server. Java use inside phpbb3 forum postings is bad and could lead to server overload because it is a security risk.

Comment: It Javascript not java , right?  Both are entirely diff.

Comment: Well excuse me, I'm a noob. But it was several times noted in the question and title, so no diff there.